# How to build javascript array for google map coordinates using MVC Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to build an array using the data from an MVC Model

```
    var locations = [];
```

I'm trying to loop through the Model and build the array like this:

```
     @{var count = 0; }
    @foreach (var item in Model.Locations)
    {
    locations[count] = new locations[@item.StreetAddress, @item.Latitude, @item.Longitude, count+1];
    count++;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: So you're trying to loop througheach item in the model and add that item to the array?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`var locations = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Locations));`

Comment: This didn't work, I had to call an action in the controller and pass back JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to loop through each item and add to array? Why not just cast your list to an array? I'm assuming your **Model.Locations** is a list of Location

```
var locations = Model.Locations.ToArray();
```

There your list is cast to an array in 1 line. If your **Model.Locations** is not a list or you want to step through each item one by one for other reasons :

```
@{var count = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model.Locations)
{
    locations[Model.Locations.IndexOf(item)] = new location[@item.StreetAddress, @item.Latitude, @item.Longitude, count+1];
    count++;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I had to call an action in the controller and pass back JSON data.